# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, customvalidator

I'm currently working on an Angular project and defining a custom validator for a reactive form, and I'm having this error within the custom validators function, which being built. Below are the code and the error received.

```
 initializeForm() {
    this.registerForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      Validators.maxLength(8)]),
      confirmPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }

  matchValues(matchTo: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return control?.value === control?.parent?.controls[matchTo].value
        ? null : { isMatching: true }
    }
  }
```

The Error Message:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; } | AbstractControl[]'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; } | AbstractControl[]'.
```

Can someone explain why this happens and how to handle it the correct way?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting `control?.parent?.controls` to { [key: string]: AbstractControl; } since it has two possible types. If it's type is `AbstractControl[]`, then the index is not of type string, but of type number.

Something like this

```
 matchValues(matchTo: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      const controls = control?.parent?.controls as { [key: string]: AbstractControl; };
      let matchToControl = null;    
      if(controls) matchToControl = controls[matchTo];       
      return control?.value === matchToControl?.value
        ? null : { isMatching: true }
    }
```

Comment: It gives me this error 
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'controls[matchTo]')

Comment: I can't really test this out without a working repro, but also try out the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
matchValues(matchTo: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const controls = control?.parent?.controls as { [key: string]: AbstractControl; };
  return controls && control?.value === controls[matchTo]?.value ? null : {isMatching: true}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).